# RxSwift event fired twice

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I set up this sandbox with a piece of code I got combining internal and external actions. I simplified as much as possible to reproduce the issue.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import RxSwift

class Sandbox {
    let publisher: PublishSubject<Int>

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        self.publisher = PublishSubject()

        let publisher2 = publisher.debug()
        let publisher3 = PublishSubject<Int>()
        let publisherMerge = PublishSubject.merge([publisher2, publisher3])

        let operation = publisherMerge
            .map { $0 + 2 }

        let operation2 = operation
            .map { $0 + 3 }

        // Will never fire on the sandbox
        operation
            .filter { $0 < 0 }
            .flatMapLatest(Sandbox.doSomething)
            .subscribe { print("Operation ", $0) }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        operation2
            .subscribe { print("Operation2 ", $0) }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    static func doSomething(value: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
        return .just(value)
    }
}

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let sandbox = Sandbox()

Observable<Int>
    .interval(.seconds(3), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in sandbox.publisher.onNext(0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I got confused as the events are triggered twice for some reason.

```
2022-11-07 21:16:15.292: Sandbox.playground:12 (init()) -> subscribed
2022-11-07 21:16:15.293: Sandbox.playground:12 (init()) -> subscribed
2022-11-07 21:16:18.301: Sandbox.playground:12 (init()) -> Event next(0)
2022-11-07 21:16:18.302: Sandbox.playground:12 (init()) -> Event next(0)
Operation2  next(5)
```

Any approach on why is this happening and how to ensure only 1 event if fired.

## EDIT 2022-11-08T02:49:37+00:00

A better example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```swift
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import RxSwift

struct ViewModel: Equatable {
    enum State: Equatable {
        case initialized
    }
    
    let state: State
}

enum Reducer {
    enum Action {
        case dummyReducerAction(String)
    }

    enum Effect {
        case dummyEffect
    }

    struct State: Equatable {
        let viewModel: ViewModel
        let effect: Effect?
    }

    static func reduce(state: State, action: Action) -> State {
        let viewModel: ViewModel = state.viewModel
        let _: Effect? = state.effect
        let viewModelState: ViewModel.State = viewModel.state
        let noChange = State(viewModel: viewModel, effect: nil)

        switch (action, viewModelState) {
        case (.dummyReducerAction(let s), _):
            print(s, Date())
            return noChange
        }
    }

    static func fromAction(_ action: Interactor.Action) -> Action {
        switch action {
        case .dummyAction:
            return .dummyReducerAction("fromAction")
        }
    }

    static func performAsyncSideEffect(effect: Effect) -> Observable<Action> {
        switch effect {
        case .dummyEffect:
            return .just(.dummyReducerAction("performSideEffect"))
        }
    }
}

class Interactor {
    enum Action {
        case dummyAction
    }

    let action: PublishSubject<Action>
    let viewModel: BehaviorSubject<ViewModel>

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        self.action = PublishSubject()
        
        let initialViewModel = ViewModel(state: .initialized)
        let initialReducerState = Reducer.State(viewModel: initialViewModel, effect: nil)
        
        let externalAction = action.map(Reducer.fromAction).debug()
        let internalAction = PublishSubject<Reducer.Action>()
        let allActions = PublishSubject.merge([externalAction, internalAction])
        
        self.viewModel = BehaviorSubject(value: initialViewModel)
        
        let reducerState = allActions
            .scan(initialReducerState, accumulator: Reducer.reduce)
        
        let viewModelObservable = reducerState
            .map { $0.viewModel }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
        
        reducerState
            .compactMap { $0.effect }
            .flatMapLatest(Reducer.performAsyncSideEffect)
            .subscribe(internalAction)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        viewModelObservable
            .subscribe(onNext: viewModel.onNext)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let interactor = Interactor()

Observable<Int>
    .interval(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in interactor.action.onNext(.dummyAction) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Even with `share()`, the reducer is fired twice and print the action content.

with `share()`:

```
2022-11-08 11:46:05.298: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> subscribed
2022-11-08 11:46:10.310: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> Event next(dummyReducerAction("fromAction"))
fromAction 2022-11-08 02:46:10 +0000
fromAction 2022-11-08 02:46:10 +0000
```

without `share()`

```
2022-11-08 11:56:33.369: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> subscribed
2022-11-08 11:56:33.370: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> subscribed
2022-11-08 11:56:38.383: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> Event next(dummyReducerAction("fromAction"))
fromAction 2022-11-08 02:56:38 +0000
2022-11-08 11:56:38.385: Sandbox.playground:71 (init()) -> Event next(dummyReducerAction("fromAction"))
fromAction 2022-11-08 02:56:38 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every subscription gets its own stream. Since you are subscribing twice to the `operation` observable (once through `operation2` and once directly) you get two subscribe requests and two next events every time it emits a value.

If you don't want that, the solution is to use the `.share()` operator.

```
let operation = publisherMerge
    .map { $0 + 2 }
    .share()
```

I'm not sure that it's actually a problem though since there is no state depending on number of subscriptions that I can see.

### EDIT

Again, the problem is the same, you just changed which thing is being observed twice.

Maybe it will help if I explain how I figure out where the `share()` should go.

1. Find the debug() statement. I see that it's on `externalAction`
2. Is `externalAction` being shared? No, it's only being used by `allActions`.
3. Is `allActions` being shared? No, it's only being used by `reducerState`.
4. Is `reducerState` being shared? Yes, it's being used by `viewModelObservable` and it's explicitly subscribed to.
5. Put the share on that observable.

```
let reducerState = allActions
    .scan(initialReducerState, accumulator: Reducer.reduce)
    .share()
```

No matter how complex the example gets, the solution is to put a `share()` (or `share(replay: 1)`) on whatever Observable(s) that is being used in more than one place.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply and help. You are right the example was too simple to explain what I am trying to achieve and to show the real issue. I updated the question with a more relevant one.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for writing a runnable example. It really helps.